# Earth and Moon as seen from Mars

Tags: past-participles

As *seen* from mars

why are we using the ''seen'' form in this sentence ? what is the grammatical aspect of this ?

all i know is: when we use past participle, we always need to use have or has.

Comment: Probably you need to learn more. Past participle is used in Perfect construcion with _have, has, had, having_; but it's also used in the Passive construction with _am, are, is, was, were, be, been,_ and _being_. And it's used by itself to modify nouns. _As seen from_ is a semi-fixed phrase meaning (and short for) "as it would have been seen by someone who was located at". _As seen by_ may refer to a real sense impression - _as seen by Dr. Johnson, according to his report_. Many other verbs can be used: _as witnessed by, as told to, as told by, as mentioned above,_ etc.

Comment: @JohnLawler - A fair comment but recognising that example as a passive isn't easy for a non-native speaker. It omits both the agent and the verb "to be".  That's quite a big omission. See my example in the comments to Centaurus' answer for an example where I replace the missing components.

Comment: You're quite right, it's hard to understand. What a native speaker does is try to figure out what it could be short for. There are a lot of ways to do this, but they all come with practice.

Comment: Earth and moon as seen from Mars: http://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/3gqnpf/earth_and_moon_as_seen_from_mars/  Includes picture

Answer (score 1):

Because it is **passive voice**.  "As (they are) seen from Mars..." or "As one sees them from Mars, the Earth and the Moon..."

- "**As explained** by Prof Lawler, the past participle is used in several passive constructions in some fixed phrases."

Comment: Yes. Here's an example with all the elements of a passive sentence.  Example: *The Earth and Moon as seen from Mars would be very small.*  This can be expanded to, *The Earth and Moon as [they would be] seen [by us] from Mars would be very small.*